# Русские символы из ms sql в c# приложениях (wpf и winForms) при установленном английском языке для не Unicode приложений

Tags: c#, sql, кодировка

Здравствуйте! Проблема следующая, необходимо провести локализацию нескольких проектов.
Имеется множество данных из базы ms sql. База большая, изначально в качестве текстовых данных там идет везде varchar. Для чтения используется OleDbDataAdapter. Collation стоит Cyrillic_General_CI_AS.
При смене языка для не Unicode приложений все русские символы превращаются в знаки вопроса.
Есть ли возможность где-то по умолчанию указать в самом приложении, что нужно использовать русский язык?
Без расширения метода ToString(), т.к. используется Devexpress и перекодировать каждую ячейку таблицы не вариант.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37271/discussion-on-question-by------ms-sql--c-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PashaPash предложил хоть и не прямое решение, но требующее наименьших трудозатрат. Вместо OleDbDataAdapter использовать SqlDataAdapter. Он не умеет напрямую работать с .udl, но .udl это текстовый файл из которого можно считать информацию для подключения распарсив. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так.

```
 // Локализация форматов данных
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");

        // Локализация пользовательского интерфейса
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture =
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

Comment: Добавляю при инициализации приложения, до загрузки данных, все равно знаки вопроса

Comment: Так тут дело судя по всему не в региональных настройках, а именно в кодировке.

Comment: Везде, где искал, советуют в базе перейти с varchar на nvarchar, т.к. это Unicode. Но начальство категорически против. Поэтому надо как-то дать понять DataSet'у, что эти данные для русской версии.

Comment: И правильно советуют. А какие аргументы приводит начальство? «Раньше так делали, и будем продолжать»?

Comment: База большая, около 120 таблиц. Скрипт обновления уже достиг свыше 12к строк кода на sql. И типа сложности во всех триггерах и процедурах переделать. Вот и приходится мне искать обходные решения.

Comment: А делать cast в select - не вариант?

Comment: Не совсем вариант, там множество процедур, напрямую select я не делаю. Базой занимается другой человек.